# Saving String Input on Android

Tags: java, android

Right, I've been trying to find a solution to this for a good while, but it's just not working for some reason.

In short, what I want to do is save every input String the user inputs into a file. Every time the activity is created again, I want to re-input these strings into a new instance of an object.

This code is what I use to create the file and read info from it, used in the onCreate() method of activity

```
    try {

        String brain = "brain";
        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), brain);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }      

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String s; // This feeds the object MegaAndroid with the strings, sequentially 
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            MegaAndroid.add(s);
        }
        in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

After that, every time the user inputs some text, the strings are saved onto the file:

```
    try {

        String brain = "brain";
        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), brain);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    out.write(message); // message is a string that holds the user input
    out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For some reason, however, every time the application is killed, the data is lost.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Also, if I were to access this file from another class, how can I?

Comment: Try calling out.flush() before closing it.

Comment: Post your logcat please

Comment: is the content being saved inside the file ??

Comment: @RaghavSood i think `BufWriter.close()` would call `flush()` implicitly.

Comment: @PremGenError: why wouldn't it be? the bufferedWriter "out" use the file "file" as the parameter... Isn't that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: My first guess was that you are calling the Writer at some point and truncating the file. `new FileWriter(file,true)` calls the FileWriter object with the `append` option. Also, if you write to the file, close the app does the file exist? This will tell us if it is cleared on launch or if it was never generated.

Comment: If it is just a string being saved I would used `SharedPreferences` It is easier, you don't have to worry about whether the file is public or private, on the sdcard or internal storage. If the data is very large then yes use a file but for small stuff I think `SharedPrefences` works better.

Comment: in your case you can't use a SharedPreferences to save that text?

Comment: The data can build up to be as big as a book's worth of material, so I thought using a file would be better.

Comment: @TheCapn: How exactly do I go about doing that? Logcat?

Comment: Then yeah a file should be better.

Comment: Android documentation: This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed). –

Comment: @TheCapn: Actually, using FileWriter(file,true) works, and the data is saved, but as only one string of words (all inputted strings are displayed as one string, not one by one).

Comment: I think that may have more to do with how you construct `message`. Where is the write operation performed from? Some ActionListener?

Comment: @TheCapn string is taken from a editText view:                   EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageText);
     String message = editText.getText().toString();

Comment: Try adding `out.newLine();` after `out.write(message);`. Does that give you the behavior you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the commend section the chief problem with the code is that your execution of `FileWriter` occurred prior to your `FileReader` operation while truncating the file. For you to maintain the file contents you want to set the write operation to an `append`:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
out.write(message);
out.newLine();
out.close();
```

However, if every entry on the EditText is received then shipped into the file you'll just be writing data byte after byte beside it. It is easy to get contents similar to

This is line #1This is line #2

Instead of the desired

This is line #1
This is line #2

which would be corrected by having the BufferedWriter pass a newline after each write to the file.

Comment: Yup, worked perfectly. Thank you very much, you're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do for file reading.

```
try{

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/whereyouwantfile");
        dir.mkdirs();

        Log.d(TAG,"path: "+dir.getAbsolutePath());
        File file = new File(dir, "VERSION_FILENAME");

        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);

        //FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(VERSION_FILENAME);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));

        String line = reader.readLine();
        Log.d(TAG,"first line versions: "+line);
        while(line != null){
            Log.d(TAG,"line: "+line);
            //Process line how you need 
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        reader.close();
        f.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"Error retrieving cached data.");

    }
```

And the following for writing

```
try{

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/whereyouwantfile");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir, "CONTENT_FILENAME");

        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(CONTENT_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(f));

        Set<String> keys = Content.keySet();

        for(String key : keys){

            String data = Content.get(key);
            Log.d(TAG,"Writing: "+key+","+data);

            writer.write(data);
            writer.newLine();
        }

        writer.close();
        f.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG,"Error writing cached data.");

    }
```

You can use the private mode if you don't want the rest of the world to be able to see your files, but it is often useful to see them when debugging.